# What does $m(I)$ stand for in the following proof?

Tags: analysis, notation, lp-spaces

In the following proof, it is shown that $f_n$ converging to $f$ uniformly implies convergence in $L^{2}$.

> If $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly (i.e. $\sup_{x \in I}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \to 0$), then 
>   $$\|f_n-f\|^2_2=\int_I |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2\,dx \leq m(I) \left(\sup_{x \in I}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\right)^2 \to 0,$$ 
>   so $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^2$.

I was wondering what $m(I)$ stands for?

Comment: Can you provide a link for this text ? It should be defined there.

Comment: may be measure (i.e., length) of interval $I$ (e.g., $b-a$ if $I=[a,b]$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$m(I)$ may indicate the [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) of interval $I$.  For example, if $I=[a,b]$, then $m(I)=b-a$.

Comment: Lebesgue measure